# SQL:How to select data with a comma in the datafield?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

Table `A`:

```
id  book_title 
-----------------
1   Harry,Potter
2   Limitless
```

Case 1:

```
select * from A where book_title like '%Harry%'

Output:
1 Harry,Potter
```

It works

but in case 2:

```
select * from A where book_title like '%HarryPotter%'

Output:
<Nothing>
```

Of course, because this parameter must match HarryPotter.

Is there any sql statement that can show the output as below:

```
Parameter: HarryPotter
SQL: ?
Output: 1   Harry,Potter
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While doing the `LIKE`, first use `REPLACE` to remove any `,` from book_title:

```
select * from A where replace(book_title,',','') like '%HarryPortter%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just insert comma in your where statement or use % if you are not sure, what is between those two words:

```
select * from A where book_title like '%Harry%Portter%'
```

Comment: It it work when parameter can be change. Anyway,thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need [find_in_set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function try something like

```
SELECT ... WHERE FIND_IN_SET('Harry', field)
```